# Widget data doesn't update when scrolling - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, today-extension

I have a widget with data. When I launch today extension my widget data is updating and showing in real time. But when I scroll the notification center and return to my widget, it doesn't update. I tried several different methods but they didn't help me. I wrote below the last method which I tried.

```
     override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "updateLabels", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
        // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

        // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResult.Failed
        // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResult.NoData
        // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResult.NewData
        completionHandler(.NewData)
    }


   func updateLabels() {
        runtimeLabel.text = returnTime() + "     " + returnDay()
    }

    func returnTimeInterval() -> NSTimeInterval {
        let uptime = NSProcessInfo().systemUptime
        return uptime
    }

    func returnTime() -> String {
        dateFormatter.unitsStyle = .Short
        dateFormatter.allowedUnits = [.Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second]
        dateFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .Pad
        let time = dateFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval(returnTimeInterval())!
        return time
    }

    func returnDay() -> String {
        dateFormatter.unitsStyle = .Short
        dateFormatter.allowedUnits = [.Year, .Month, .Day]
        dateFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .Pad
        let date = NSDate(timeInterval: -returnTimeInterval(), sinceDate: NSDate())
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
        let megaDate = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
        return megaDate
    }
```

Comment: What does your updateLabels method look like?

Comment: @user2893289 I updated my code

Comment: Have you checked that your updateLabels method is called?

Comment: Yes, I did. In the first time widget is updating but I scroll or when I return in app and launch today extension widget doesn't update.

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution for that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same and it worked with the code below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!
var timer = NSTimer()
var counter = 0

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateLabel"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

    func updateLabel(){
            counter += 1
            myLabel.text = "Test \(counter)"
        }
```

Update:

`viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` should be called after when the widget is active and `viewDidDisappear` should be called when scrolling (leaving the widget). As for now the `viewDidDisappear` is working as expected but not `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` on scrolling.

It´s a known bug that this is not working properly, you can read more information in this [post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16348) at Apples forum and check the bug status report [here](http://www.openradar.me/22545070).

Comment: This action launched only once.

Comment: @Alexsander this seems to be a known bug, check my update.

Comment: @Alexsander has this bug been fixed yet? the apple forum discussion is closed, but I'm still having the same issue on xcode 7.2, ios 9.2

Answer (score 0):

You should write your update code in `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler` method.